# Laravel 8 darkaonline/l5-swagger in create the root directory

Tags: laravel, swagger-ui, laravel-8

we install the package:

```
composer require darkaonline/l5-swagger
```

Next, following installation instructions in Readme, we publish config/views from Service Provider:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider "L5Swagger\L5SwaggerServiceProvider"
```

but the following error occurs.

```
PS D:\aWeb-dev\drugs\kainos-multy> php artisan vendor:publish --provider "L5Swagger\L5SwaggerServiceProvider"

   League\Flysystem\Exception 

  Impossible to create the root directory "".

  at D:\aWeb-dev\drugs\kainos-multy\vendor\league\flysystem\src\Adapter\Local.php:112
    108▕             clearstatcache(false, $root);
    109▕
    110▕             if ( ! is_dir($root)) {
    111▕                 $errorMessage = isset($mkdirError['message']) ? $mkdirError['message'] : '';
  ➜ 112▕                 throw new Exception(sprintf('Impossible to create the root directory "%s". %s', $root, $errorMessage));
    113▕             }
    114▕         }
    115▕     }
    116▕

  1   D:\aWeb-dev\drugs\kainos-multy\vendor\league\flysystem\src\Adapter\Local.php:78
      League\Flysystem\Adapter\Local::ensureDirectory()

  2   D:\aWeb-dev\drugs\kainos-multy\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\VendorPublishCommand.php:238
      League\Flysystem\Adapter\Local::__construct()
```

Comment: look like permission issue

Comment: what kind of permission issue

Comment: look like folder permission .just try to give root folder read write access